# I am Trying to Deploy a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric for a single organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

While Deploying its asking me to create a connection.json file but where my worry is where do i need to place that file and also when i give the command :-- composer card create -p connection.json -u PeerAdmin -c Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k 114aab0e76bf0c78308f89efc4b8c9423e31568da0c340ca187a9b17aa9a4457_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin

its  giving the error as command not found 
so my worry is where to place the connection.json and what are the next procedure i need to follow

Comment: hi there, there is an end-to-end tutorial that describes this https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org - you can create `connection.json` in the current directory (as described) - upon creation of the card (your command above), it subsequently gets imported and Composer takes care of storing the new PeerAdmin card (in this case), complete with its `connection.json`,  in the Composer wallet directory . `command not found` suggests you've not installed Composer correctly (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to put the connection profile in tmp directory as following

```
mkdir -p /tmp/composer/org1
```

then

```
cd /tmp/composer/org1
```

then

```
nano byfn-network-org1.json
```

then copy the connection profile setting in this file and save it.

then create crypto material for your admin

```
export ORG1=crypto- 
config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
cp -p $ORG1/signcerts/A*.pem /tmp/composer/org1
cp -p $ORG1/keystore/*_sk /tmp/composer/org1
```

then you can create your admin card using the following command

```
composer card create -p /tmp/composer/org1/byfn-network-org1.json -u PeerAdmin -c /tmp/composer/org1/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k /tmp/composer/org1/*_sk -r PeerAdmin -r ChannelAdmin -f PeerAdmin@org1.card
```

hope you this helpful